# How to pass parameters when calling a function without the parenthesis [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

I have a function called "tryMe" and I'm calling it without the parenthesis not precisely this but the idea is like what you would do here:

```
setTimeout(tryMe,200);
```

how can I pass parameters that I need?

I am using a jquery plugin that enables me to call a function but I have to call it withou the parenthesis or it executes itself upon loading.

Comment: It executes because the function is evaluated and result of the function is passed to `setTimeout`; The function itself is not passed as you are expecting.

Comment: It's not accurate to describe what you're doing as, "calling a function without the parentheses".  The function is not called in the statement you posted in your question. Rather, a *reference* to your function is passed to another function (`setTimeout`), which will at some time (200 milliseconds later, in fact) call your function **with** parentheses (conceptually). Still, what you're asking here is a very common point of confusion, and the answer is hardly obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { tryMe(parm1, parm2); }, 200);
```

<strike>A more robust offering, to ensure that the values of `parm1`, `parm2` don't change before the timeout fires (per @lincolnk's comment):</strike>

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var p1 = parm1;
   var p2 = parm2;
   tryMe(p1, p2);
}, 200);
```

@patrick dw, you're right, has to be evaluated before.

Comment: Just make sure you're not changing your parameter values before the timeout fires.

Comment: Your update won't behave any differently from the original. In order to ensure the values that were present when `setTimeout` was called, you'd need to *invoke* a function, reference them locally in *that* function, and have the function return a function that references the locally defined references.

Comment: More elegant way is to use __setTimeout(tryMe.bind(window,parm1,parm2),200);__. bind() is not supported by IE8 or less, but can be implemented with javascript equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap `tryMe` in a closure.

For example:

```
var f = function(){tryMe('some parameter');};
setTimeout(f, 200);
```

Here, we create a function object, `f`, which calls `tryMe` with the desired parameter(s).  Then we pass `f` to `setTimeout`.  When the timeout expires, `f` will be called, which will in turn call `tryMe` with the desired parameters.

A word of warning if you wish to pass in parameters that may change before the timeout gets called (for example, if you are setting several timeouts in a `for` loop): you will want to bind those variables like so:

```
var f = function(someParamter){return function(){tryMe(someParameter);};};
setTimeout(f(someParameter), 200);
```

The reason simply doing something like

```
setTimeout(tryMe('some parameter'), 200); //Does not work.
```

doesn't work is because you are passing the result of evaluating `tryMe` instead of the function object `tryMe` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function, the browser does - after 200 milliseconds. You are merely providing it with the function that needs being called. Firefox actually allows specifying additional parameters in the `setTimeout` call:

```
setTimeout(tryMe, 200, "first parameter", "second parameter");
```

However, as far as I know no other browsers support this feature so you should really use a closure function as explained by other answers already. Here you create a temporary function with the sole purpose of calling your original function with the right parameters.

```
setTimeout(function() {tryMe("first parameter", "second parameter")}, 200);
```