# Why is JavaScript's Set Timeout not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use setTimeout, But it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
var button = document.getElementById("reactionTester");
var start  = document.getElementById("start");

function init() {
    var startInterval/*in milliseconds*/ = 1000;
    setTimeout(startTimer(), startInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
    document.write("hey");
}
```

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). You are trying to access a DOM element before it exists. Please see [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196). And please explain *what exactly* is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

This line:

```
setTimeout(startTimer(), startInterval);
```

You're invoking `startTimer()`. Instead, you need to pass it in as a function *to be invoked*, like so:

```
setTimeout(startTimer, startInterval);
```

Comment: Yes, also as @j08691 notes--keeping the parens instantly triggers the function call. This was misleading me, as the function was being called without any errors or console warnings, so I wasn't doubting how I used the `setTimeout()`, but how I'd scoped it, etc. This was driving me crazy. Thanks to you both.

Comment: What if you have to pass a variable in?

Comment: @Jeff you would wrap it inside a closure.  `setTimeout(function() { startTimer(parm1); }, startInterval);`   See here for more info...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176292/how-to-pass-parameters-when-calling-a-function-without-the-parenthesis-javascri

Answer (score 36):

If your in a situation where you need to pass parameters to the function you want to execute after timeout, you can wrap the "named" function in an anonymous function.

i.e. works

```
setTimeout(function(){ startTimer(p1, p2); }, 1000);
```

i.e. won't work because it will call the function right away

```
setTimeout( startTimer(p1, p2), 1000);
```

Answer (score 13):

Two things.

1. Remove the parenthesis in `setTimeout(startTimer(),startInterval);`. Keeping the parentheses invokes the function immediately.
2. Your startTimer function will overwrite the page content with your use of `document.write` (without the above fix), and wipes out the script and HTML in the process.

Comment: What if you have to pass a variable in?

Comment: @Jeff - Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, that was worded badly. I figured out what I was trying to do... I was trying to pass a function that requires a variable as my first argument. I just wrapped it in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass a parameter to the delayed function:

```
    setTimeout(setTimer, 3000, param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
setTimeout(startTimer,startInterval);
```

You're calling startTimer() and feed it's result (which is undefined) as an argument to setTimeout().

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code as follows:

```
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("reactionTester");
    var start = document.getElementById("start");
    function init() {
        var startInterval/*in milliseconds*/ = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)*1000;
        setTimeout(startTimer,startInterval); 
    }
    function startTimer(){
        document.write("hey");
    }
</script>
```

See if that helps.  Basically, the difference is references the 'startTimer' function instead of executing it.

Answer (score 1):

To make little more easy to understand use like below, which i prefer the most. Also it permits to call multiple function at once. Obviously

```
setTimeout(function(){
      startTimer();
      function2();
      function3();
}, startInterval);
```