# Value to a function inside a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to set a time out with a value, looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890943/javascript-settimeout-not-working) I found out that having any form of `setTimeout(function(), int);` will 'skip' the timer, how would I do it to my code below?

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("remove");
  setTimeout(hide(this),2000);
});
function hide(name) {
  $(name).remove();
}
```

Output

```
".addtimer div" disappears instantly
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from this:

```
setTimeout(hide(this),2000);
```

to this:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    hide(self);
},2000);
```

You were calling the function immediately and passing its return value to `setTimeout` rather than passing a function reference to `setTimeout` that can be called later.   Keep in mind that `(xx)` means execute now.  So `hide(this)` means to execute it now, not later.  On the other hand, `function() { hide(this); }` is a function reference that can be called later.

---

Or, if you aren't using the hide function anywhere else, then you can integrate it in like this:

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("remove");
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
         $(self).remove();
    },2000);
});
```

---

A useful language feature is `.bind()` which can be used to "hardwire" the value of `this` or of arguments to callback functions.  For example, you could do this:

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("remove");
    setTimeout(function() {
         $(this).remove();
    }.bind(this),2000);
});
```

The `.bind(this)` sets the current value of `this` to be the value of `this` when the callback function is called.

Or, if you still have the function `hide(item)`, then you could use .bind to set the argument to `hide()` like this:

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("remove");
    setTimeout(hide.bind(null, this)), 2000);
});
```

---

Or, you could use an animation and let it provide the timing for you:

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("remove").delay(1000).slideUp(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

As you can see, there are lots of options and which to use depends a bit on the situation, what you think makes the clearest code in your situation and what you are most comfortable in using.

Comment: Thank you, knew there was a better way

Comment: Added two other options to the answer.

Comment: Ussch to using `var self = this;` As he is using jQuery then I'd go for [`.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/). Otherwise I'd use `bind` or a `closure` (which I believe `proxy` uses for cross browser purposes).

Comment: @Xotic750 - I added a couple `.bind()` options.  I don't see any reason to use `$.proxy()`.  Its main benefit was for when `.bind()` was not well supported across browsers.  I'd much rather use the actual language feature now than a copy of it now that `.bind()` is well supported.

Comment: Totally agree with using actual well supported language features over jQuery. Let the old and broken die. :P

Answer (score 4):

The first issue is that you need to pass a function to `setTimeout` (you were not; you were calling the function and passing its return value to `setTimeout`), and the second is that you need to handle `this` correctly.

There are two main ways to get the `this` handling right.

With `.bind()`:

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("remove");

    // you could also use   function () { hide(this); }.bind(this)
    setTimeout(hide.bind(null, this), 2000);
});
function hide(name) {
    $(name).remove();
}
```

Or with an alias variable:

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("remove");
    var self = this; 
    setTimeout(function () { hide(self) }, 2000);
});
function hide(name) {
    $(name).remove();
}
```

One more option would be to get rid of the use of `this` altogether and use `e.target` (since this is a jQuery DOM event handler):

```
$(".addtimer div").click(function (e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass("remove");
    setTimeout(function () { hide(e.target) }, 2000);
});
function hide(name) {
    $(name).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned jQuery's [`.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/), I thought it best to give an example.

```js
function hide(name) {
    $(name).remove();
}

$('.addtimer div').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('remove');
    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
        hide(this);
    }, this), 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addtimer">
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

And with native [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
function hide(name) {
    $(name).remove();
}

$('.addtimer div').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('remove');
    setTimeout(function () {
        hide(this);
    }.bind(this), 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addtimer">
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

And with a [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

```js
function hide(name) {
    $(name).remove();
}

$('.addtimer div').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('remove');
    setTimeout((function (element) {
        return function () {
            hide(element);
        };
    }(this)), 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addtimer">
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

But of course none of this is necessary if you dropped the `this` and used the event argument of the callback.

```js
function hide(name) {
    $(name).remove();
}

$('.addtimer div').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).toggleClass('remove');
    setTimeout(function () {
        hide(e.target);
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addtimer">
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

And in modern ECMA5

```js
function hide(name) {
    name.parentNode.removeChild(name);
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.addtimer div'), function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.classList.toggle('remove');
        setTimeout(function () {
            hide(e.target);
        }, 2000);
    }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="addtimer">
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```