# How to pass parameter in function in modular pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Javascript function;

```
var searchbox=function(){
    var _expandbox=function(count){
    };

    var _events=function(){
        setTimeout(_expandbox,3000);
    }

    var _init=function(){
        _events();
    };

    return {
        init: _init
    };
}();

$(document).ready(function(){
    searchbox.init();
});
```

Here the problem is if I call function like setTimeout(_expandbox(4),3000) it won't work.So plese help me how to add parameter in function.

Comment: It's like the first hit on Google with the frase *"setTimeout not working"* -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890943/javascript-settimeout-not-working

Comment: I am not talking about why setTimeout is not working.My qustion is about how to pass parameter in function in modular javascript pattern.

Comment: Doesn't matter what pattern you're using, calling a function rather than referencing it in `setTimeout` is your issue, and it's a duplicate of several other questions, and the answer below is the same as those duplicates.

Comment: Lets look at a simpler example: `foo(bar())`. This will *first* call `bar` and pass its return value to `foo`. That's how pretty much every common programming language works. The same happens with `setTimeout(_expandbox(4),3000)`. It calls `_expandbox(4)` and passes the return value (which is `undefined`) to `setTimeout`. I.e. it's equivalent to `setTimeout(undefined, 3000)`. However, `setTimeout` expects a function that it can call in the future, not `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() { _expandbox(4); }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you.Actually I want to know why   setTimeout(_expandbox(4),3000); can't  give correct answer.

Comment: The first parameter for setTimeout is a function, `setTimeout(_expandbox(4),3000);` is passing the return value of `_expandbox(4)` as parameter, which is invalid.

Comment: @Dhwani91 - whenever you add the parentheses you call the function immediately and pass the returned value, which in this case is `undefined` to `setTimeout`. There's a difference in **calling** a function with the parentheses, and **referencing** a function with it's name only, to be invoked later.

Comment: Thanks.now it clears my doubt,@adeneo