# adding images to document in loop

Tags: javascript

I have written this javascript code to add images each after a delay of 3 seconds but this code is not working kindly help.

```
function start() {
    while(true) {
        setTimeout(addObstracles(), 3000)
    }
}

function addObstracle() {
        var element = document.createElement('img');    
        element.id = 'obs';
        element.className = 'obstracleAnimation';
        element.src = 'enemy.png';
        element.style.position = 'absolute';
        element.style.top = '0px';
        element.style.left = '100%';
        element.style.width = '150px';
        element.style.height = '100px';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Better define "not working".

Comment: images are not being generated

Comment: Perhaps because you're *calling* addObstracles in your `setTimeout` call, and that method doesn't return anything..

Comment: Are there any dev console errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript setTimeout() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890943/javascript-settimeout-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` takes a function reference. You have a function invokation.

There are multiple ways to write this out:

```
setTimeout('addObstracles()', 3000) //i don't like this way
setTimeout(addObstracles, 3000) // pass the reference (I like this way!)
setTimeout(function() {
    addObstracles()
}, 3000) //I like this when `addObstracles has parameters!
```

Comment: He also calls addObstacles instead of addObstacle.

Comment: @SajalAli check your JavaScript console and you'll see some nice red error messages that will help you out

Answer (score 2):

Like Sterling mentioned in his anser, you are calling the function `addObstracles` instead of passing it to `setTimeout`, just i want to add to it that because you are setting timout functions on fixed intervals you can use `setInterval` function instead:

```
function start() {
    setInterval (addObstracles, 3000);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/xdcx51ew/)

Comment: still not working, this freezes the browser

Comment: `id` attribute is unique, you can assign it to one element only, remove `element.id = 'obs';` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this code. I will add to the answers the following:

- be careful what function you define and what function you call: something != somethings
- be careful where you call your `start()` function: it has to be after the body tag or `body.appendChild` won't exist
- be careful how you style your element. With the current styling, it is not displayed at all. I have just removed `element.style.position = 'absolute';` to make it visible
- make sure the image you are trying to display is in the same folder as the script