# Sequential programming with setTimeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried using `setTimeout` but I added `pizzaTask` method, the `setTimeout` doesn't seem to work. Yes, I do not want any async or promises here.

```js
function preparePizza(n) {
  console.log("Finish preparing pizza " + n);
  console.log("Start baking pizza " + n);
  setTimeout(bakePizza, 10000);
}

function bakePizza() {
  console.log("Finish baking pizza");
}

function makePizza(n) {
  console.log("Start preparing pizza " + n);
  setTimeout(preparePizza(n), 5000);
}

function pizzaTask() {
  for (let x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    makePizza(x);
  }

  console.log("Read to take new order ...");
}

pizzaTask();
```

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function - you pass it the return of a function, which is `undefined`, because you call the function inside the brackets.

Comment: You can wrap your `preparePizza` call in an arrow function so that you're still able to pass `n` into `preparePizza` without executing it immediately. `setTimeout(() => { preparePizza(n) }, 5000);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890943/javascript-settimeout-not-working proper dupe, along with the non-descriptive "it's not working!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you're calling `preparePizza(n)`, this calls the function which returns `undefined`. You need to pass a function and call it within this function as `preparePizza` takes an argument `n`. Solution below.

```js
  function preparePizza(n) {
    console.log("Finish preparing pizza " + n);
    console.log("Start baking pizza " + n);
    setTimeout(bakePizza, 10000);
  }

  function bakePizza() {
    console.log("Finish baking pizza");
  }

  function makePizza(n) {
    console.log("Start preparing pizza " + n);
    setTimeout(function() {
      preparePizza(n)
    }, 5000);
  }

  function pizzaTask() {
    for (let x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
      makePizza(x);
    }

    console.log("Read to take new order ...");
   }
  
   pizzaTask();
```

Comment: but how to make `console.log("Read to take new order ...");` run after finish making all the pizza?

Comment: and it starts to prepare all the 10 pizza at the same time. How to make it prepare the pizza only after the current pizza finished bakePizza?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is promise chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining